# Java distance between two points of an array?

Tags: java

So this is an unique question and I would appreciate any help.

The objective:
To count and return an integer of 'distance' from min value to max value. 
The list is not sorted and should not be sorted. 
Min value might be before max or vise-verse.
In a list of { 2, -5, -7, 8, 22, -10 } answer = 1 (the distance from -10 to 22)
In a list of { 2, -5, -7, 8, 22, -6 } answer = 2 (the distance from -7 to 22)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: no reason sorry, you can add another if, if you like.

Comment: It seems to me that you need to identify the index of where the MIN and MAX values are.  Then simply subtract one from the other.  In this case, you would have an index of 2 and an index of 4, for a spread of 2

Comment: @durbnpoisn, we haven't yet covered index's either....does it work the same in java as in python?

Comment: I find it kind of amusing that they are teaching you about arrays, but left out the fundamental concept of the index.  Without which, arrays make no sense at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep track of the corresponding index:

```
double min = list[0];
int minIndex = 0;
double max = list[0];
int maxIndex = 0;
for (int i =1 ; i < list.length ; i++) {
    if(min > list[i]){
        min = list[i];
        minIndex = i;
    }
    if(max < list[i]){
        max = list[i];
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}
int res = Math.abs(minIndex - maxIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you. makes perfect sense

Comment: FYI - this assumes that the items in the list are unique (the OP didn't say one way or the other).  For instance, using the OP's sample of `{ 2, -5, -7, 8, 22, -6 }` correctly yields 2.  However, adding another -7 element to the beginning of the list changes the output, which may or may not be desired (again, not specified).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...your assumption is correct. There are no duplicates in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the indice while finding `max` and `min` :

```
int indMin = 0;
int indMax = 0;
double min = list[0];
double max = list[0];
for (int i =0; i<list.length;i++){
    if(min>list[i]){
        min=list[i];
        indMin = i;
    }
    if(max<list[i]){
        max = list[i];
        indMax = i;
    }
}

int distance = Math.abs(indMax - indMin);
```

Comment: This is wrong. If the array is ``{1, 2}`` then it will return ``abs(1 - (-1)) = 2``